# Remove <br> from inside of a tag

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string from database and it's written incorrect:

```
$string = " <P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">M</SPAN>.Of. <br />nr. 1 din 5 ianuarie 1998</SPAN></P><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><br /><P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><FONT <br />color=#0000ff>NOTA ETO a se vedea: 1)&nbsp;Regulamentele</FONT> <A <br />href="doc:910013103/33">nr. 131/1991,&nbsp;<A <br />href="doc:1010117203/2">1172/2001,&nbsp;<A <br />href="doc:1050089003/2">890/2005.</SPAN></P><br /><P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /><FONT color=#0000ff>2)&nbsp;Norme metodologice <A <br />href="doc:1020012755/5">nr.127/2002.</FONT></SPAN></P><br /><P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN <br />style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><FONT <br />color=#0000ff>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3)&nbsp;Metodologie&nbsp;<A <br />href="doc:1070064010/25">nr.640/2007.&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></P><br /> ";
```

I have `<br />` tags inside other tags and i don't know how to remove the br

i tried with regular expression

```
$no_br = preg_replace('/(.*<.*)<br \/>(^.*>.*)/i',"$1 $2",$string);
```

but it doesn't work

**I don't want to remove all the `<br />`, just the ones inside the tags**

I already used  `$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n" ), "<br />", $row['val'] );` to transform \n into breakline because i am using this text inside a webview for a mobile app

Answer (score 1):

replace th `<br/>` tag with **newline**

```
   $string =  preg_replace("#<br\s*/?>#i", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: i don't want to remove all the <br> , only the ones inside the html tags. I am using this code in a webview  for a mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
preg_replace('/(<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]*){3,}/', '<br /><br />', $string);
```

or

```
$string=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*){2,}}i", "<br /><br />", $string);
$string=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*)}i", "<br />", $string);
```

Comment: i want to remove the <br> from inside the tags

Answer (score 0):

To remove all permutations of br:

```
<br> <br /> <br/> <br   >
```

check out the user contributed [`strip_only()`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) function.

```
echo strip_tags($string, '<br><br /><br/><br >');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('~<[^>]*>~', function ($m) { 
    return str_replace('<br />', '', $m[0]); }
, $s);
```

Or, for corrupt or untidy HTML:

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('~<[^>]*>~', function ($m) { 
    return preg_replace('~<\s*br\s*/?\s*>~i', '', $m[0]); }
, $s);
```

The point is:

- All element nodes are matched with `<[^>]*>` regex (`<`, then 0+ chars other than `>`and then `>`)
- The match is passed to the anonymous function in the `preg_replace_callback` and the
- `str_replace('<br />', '', $m[0])` replaces all `<br />` with empty strings **only** inside the matched text. To account for any variants of `<br>` you may use another `preg_replace`, `preg_replace('~<\s*br\s*/?\s*>~i', '', $m[0])`.